# setInterval - can I make it recognize "this"

Tags: javascript

I'm not even sure how to ask this question but I've pared down the code to the simplest possible example I could:

```
function Handler() {}
Handler.prototype.texts = [];
Handler.prototype.add = function(d) {
  this.texts.push(d);
};
Handler.prototype.tick = function() {
  console.log( this.texts );
};

var x = new Handler();
setInterval( x.tick, 5000 );

x.add('beatles');
```

when setInterval calls x.tick, it gives a value of undefined for this.texts - and, of course, for `this`. while I can solve the problem via

```
setInterval( x.tick, 5000, x );

// and ... in the prototype
Handler.prototype.tick = function(myObj) {
    console.log( myObj.texts );
}
```

It feels a bit clunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
setInterval( x.tick.bind(x), 5000 );
```

There are working shims to support older browsers as well:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Important to note that this will only work in modern browsers ;)

Comment: this is for node, so not worried much about browsers. I like this method more then the one above, seems custom made for this.

Answer (score 5):

make `x` an upvalue like so

```
setInterval(function(){
  x.tick()
}, 5000);
```

When `setInterval` fires, a closure will be created around the instance of `x`.